# Is the order of answers with equal votes still random?

Tags: support, answers, sorting

Is [Jeff Atwood's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239/answer-ordering#comment50763_239) still up-to-date? Will the order of answers be random if the score is equal or is there an algorithm implemented?

Comment: What makes you suspect it has changed?

Comment: @Emrakul - Wouldn't it be nicer that it could do a secondary sort in such a case(may be sort on the time at the which answer was posted)?

Comment: @R.J [The randomisation was a countermeasure to FGITW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/223030), so secondary sorting by creation time would defeat the purpose.

Comment: @Emrakul Time did. I was reading about the FGITW problem and therefore thought that maybe a new approach is used these days. Thx for clearify this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The order of the answers is random if the **score is equal** and you are **on the *votes* tab**.

Hit refresh on such a question and you will see that the order changes. Of course accepted answers are an exception and stay on top*.

<sub>* If not self answers</sub>

Comment: Mention that accepted answers from someone else than the question author floats always on top.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Could the answer be accepted by someone else than the question author? I think that the answer could only be accepted by the asker.

Comment: @xshsinap The question author can accept his own answer, which IIRC does not get this special handling.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yes, I understand what you mean now. Thanks.